# How to pass data between fragments of a FragmentTabHost?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to learn android and am having an issue with this project.  I have set up a fragment tab host with four fragments. What I would like to do is have the first three fragments be interactive with the user and when they tab over to the 4th tab, it will display all the information they put in on the first three. I figured I can pass the info overriding on onPause() as the trigger as I don't want to use a button press. Right now, I'm just trying to get the EditText to work to make sure I'm doing everything right. I'm not sure if I'm using the fragment transaction correctly, or the way I'm trying to collect the edit text field.  Later on I hope to pass the information via a bundle.  Any help would be appreciated.

Main:

```
package valdes.fragmenttabsmenu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements WelcomeFragment.WelcomeListener {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
private String firstName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Home").setIndicator("Home", null), WelcomeFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Demographics").setIndicator("Demographics", null), DemographicsFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Questions").setIndicator("Questions", null), QuestionsFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Overview").setIndicator("Overview", null), OverviewFragment.class, null);
}


@Override
public void getFristName(String first_Name){
    firstName = first_Name;
    OverviewFragment fragment = new OverviewFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragment.setFirstName(firstName);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

}
}
```

Fragment 1 - getting info

```
package valdes.fragmenttabsmenu;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {


public WelcomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

interface WelcomeListener{
    public void getFristName(String firstName);

}

private WelcomeListener listener;
private String firstName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
    EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    firstName = editText.getText().toString();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.listener = (WelcomeListener)context;
}



@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
   if(listener != null){
       listener.getFristName(firstName);
   }
}
}
```

Fragment 1 XML

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="@string/welcome_message"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/first_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/first_name"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/last_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/last_name"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/birthday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/months"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment 2 - getting info

```
package valdes.fragmenttabsmenu;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;


public OverviewFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    if(view != null){
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.OV_name);
        name.setText(firstName);

    }
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){this.firstName = firstName;}

}
```

Fragment 2 XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="valdes.fragmenttabsmenu.OverviewFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/overview"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:text="Responses go here"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/OV_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="TEST"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Listner for get/set data between fragments and implement it on activity like this

InteractionLister.java

```
public interface InteractionLister {

    void setData(String data);

    String getData();

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity implements InteractionLister{

    private String mData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String getData() {
        return mData;
    }
}
```

TabFragment1.java

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
    InteractionLister interactionLister;
    private static final String TAG = TabFragment1.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w(TAG,"Data from other fragment " + interactionLister.getData());

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        interactionLister = (InteractionLister) activity;
    }
}
```